# cors error in authentication type windows - visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication, webapi

I started a .NET CORE 5 project

And I chose windows type authentication

[type authentication image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xay5n.png)

And this type of project gives me a CORS error on the client side (react)

But if instead of windows I choose none, I won't get an error

This is the call from the client side:

```
const res = await fetch(`https://localhost:44373/weatherforecast`)
```

I need this type of project because I want to use AD authentication

I tried adding it to the fetch call:

```
const res = await fetch(`https://localhost:44300/weatherforecast`,{credentials: 'include'})
```

and change the STARTUP:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to 
add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("MyMyAllowCredentialsPolicy",
                    policy =>
                    {
                        policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44300")
                               .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to 
configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseCors();

            app.UseRouting();

             app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can try to [include the credential](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies) in your fetch method --> `fetch('https://xxx', {credentials: 'include'})` and [enable credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests) in your api too ---> `policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowCredentials();`

Comment: It doesn't work for me,I am attaching the STARTUP file to the question

Comment: Did you test with .AllowAnyOrigin() method? I guess this would work

Comment: I checked, but changed it to what Tiny wang said..

Comment: At first I think Cors issue may related to cors policy, but as you mentioned that disable windows authentication will make it work, so I think you've set the cors policy, so I deduce that it may relate to `AllowCredentials()`. Since it still failed to work. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450854/how-to-authorize-cors-preflight-request-on-iis-with-windows-authentication) which looks like similar to your scenario, could you pls take a look at it?

Comment: I worked according to what is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197165/how-to-resolve-cors-error-in-react-with-asp-net-core And if I add the AuthenticationMiddleware class
I get a 401 error

Comment: I did a test in my side and it worked for me, since I don't know react, so my frontend app is a normal html app. I've added my code below, pls take a look at them.

Comment: What is defined for you here:
anonymousAuthentication
in launchsettings file?

Comment: Now I see that in GET calls it works,
But in other things it doesn't work (POST, PUT, DELETE)

Comment: For me, I added the post api in the controller and test in the client, it still worked for me.

Comment: Can you send me your POST reading?

Comment: I've updated my test result

Answer (score 0):

I also created a new .net 6 web api project with windows authentication. I also had a front end project.

This is my code and it worked for me. In my `Program.cs`, I added Cors policy and others are generated by default.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("mypolicy",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8848").AllowCredentials();
                   //.AllowCredentials();
        });
});
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("mypolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

And I used ajax to send the request, missing `withCredentials` will lead to 401 error:

```
$("#btn2").click(function(event) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://localhost:7272/WeatherForecast",
                    type: "get",
                    xhrFields: {
                        withCredentials: true
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        console.info(data);
                    }
                })
            });
```

Another point which needs to notice is that, when opening the client website in the private mode, it will still meet 401 while everything worked well when open the website in the normal window. That is because private mode doesn't contain auth information I think.

[image]

For Post request, still worked.

[image]

Post with parameters??

[image]

Comment: I changed to AJAX calls, but POST calls with parameters does not work for me

Comment: still worked .... to be honest I don't why the parameter would influence the request, do I misunderstand it?