No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, using ReactJS with NetCore. How to make AllowAnyOrigin work
Im using ReactJS and Net Core as backend.
As soon as I put up a request via to my Net Core, I was responded with a message
http://localhost:8080/auth/someendpoint' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I've set my Startup.cs:
//Add CORS
        //for development env
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
        });

and use it like:
app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");


could you pls share how you send your request? does it contain any credentials? In the mean time, do you use any authentication mechanism in your web api? By the way, if you used windows authentication, could you pls help check this case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400474

Update:
finally fixed it, seems like this happens because im trying to use a custom header on my request, i deleted it and it works
